# Is it possible to change the appearance of top level menus in Qt?

Tags: qt, winapi, qt4

I'm using the latest version of Qt and noticed that on Windows the menus are rendered in a very old-school fashion (similar to the way they look on other cross platform apps, like Firefox). I want the menu rendering (colors, gradient, etc.) to take on a more modern appearance. Is it possible to skin or modify the way menus are rendered in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Qt or Windows you're using, but on my Windows 7 computer with Qt 4.8.1 installed, the default menus look normal, like any other Windows 7 menu.

To change the look of a menu, you have two broad (easy) options:

1. Use [QStyle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html) to change it to a different "native" look (use `QApplication::setStyle()` or `QWidget::setStyle()`). For example, you can make it look like a Windows XP menu like this:

   ```
   fileMenu->setStyle(new QWindowsXPStyle);
   ```
2. Use Qt [style sheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu) to customize how you want the menu to be rendered. For example:

   ```
   fileMenu->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
   ```

Comment: Ok, but who is responsible for deleting the new'd style instance? Is that the fileMenu that does that during application shutdown? Or did your answer create a memory leak?

Comment: @987S I'm not absolutely certain, but this is how it's done both in the docs and in the Qt books I've read. So I'm 99% sure the menu will take ownership of the style, and delete it at the appropriate time.